# Is it 100% accurate to think of a Python dictionary as merely a two column table?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been noodling around with Python for quite a while in my spare time, and while I have sort of understood and definitely used dictionaries, they've always seemed somewhat foreign to me, like I wasn't quite getting them.  Maybe it's the name "dictionary" throwing me off, of the fact I started way back when with Basic (I know) which had arrays, but they were quite different.

Can I simply think of a dictionary in Python as nothing more or less than a two-column table where we name the contents of the first column "keys" and the contents of the second column "values"? Is this conceptualization extremely accurate and useful, or problematic?

If the former, I think I can finally swallow the concept in such a way to finally make it more natural to my thinking.

Comment: It's close enough, as long as you don't expect the mapping to work the other way; you can find a value given a key, but you can't find a key given a value without having to scan through the whole table.

Comment: The 100% accurate way to think of a CPython dictionary is as an associative array implemented as a hash table.

Comment: I find it helps enough to just think of a dictionary as the physical book dictionary, you look up a definition based off of a keyword. But in a simplistic term I guess you can, just don't expect the rows to maintain the same order

Comment: It depends on how far you take the metaphor. Suppose you have a two column table with 10,000 entries. How long would it take you to determine whether "foo" is a key in the table? You might need to check every entry, or maybe just skim two dozen if you had the foresight to alphabetize everything. But a Python dictionary has O(1) lookup, which is more efficient than any two column table you can make in real life.

Comment: If you have 30 minutes, this is a great video to watch about dicts, from one of the people involved in their implementation in python - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npw4s1QTmPg

Comment: I'll definitely watch that video, thanks.

Comment: @Sindyr that's a great video, but honestly, it goes pretty far into the weeds as far as what's going on under the hood. It might be better to grok what a dictionary does *abstractly* and then look at that video when you start to wonder "gee, how does this amazing data-structure work so well!?"

Comment: If you think of dicts this way, you're likely to use them everywhere a two-column table seems reasonable, even when other data structures (like a list of tuples) may be more appropriate. You might also subconsciously limit the kinds of keys and values you use, avoiding nested data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analogy of a 2-column table might work to some degree but it doesn't cover some important aspects of how and why dictionaries are used in practice.

The comment by @Sayse is more conceptually useful. Think of the dictionary as a physical language dictionary, where the `key` is the word itself and the `value` is the word's definition. Two items in the dictionary cannot have the same `key` but could have the same `value`. In the analogy of a language dictionary, if two words had the same spelling then they are the same word. However, synonyms can exist where two words which are spelled differently could have the same definition.

The table analogy also doesn't cover the behaviour of a dictionary where the order is not preserved or reliable. In a dictionary, the order does not matter and the item is retrieved by its `key`. Perhaps another useful analogy is to think of the `key` as a person's name and the `value` is the person themselves (and maybe lots of information about them as well). The people are identified by their names but they may be in any given order or location...it doesn't matter, since we know their names we can identify them.

While the order of items in a dictionary may not be preserved, a dictionary has the advantage of having very fast retrieval for a single item. This becomes especially significant as the number of items to lookup grows larger (on the order of thousands or more).

Finally, I would also add that dictionaries can often improve the readability of code. For example, if you wanted create a lookup table of HTML color codes, an API using a dictionary of HTML color names is much more readable and usable than using a list and relying on documentation of indices to retrieve the values.

So if it helps you to conceptualize a dictionary as a table of 2 columns, that is fine, as long as you also keep in mind the rules for their use and the scenarios where they provide some benefit:

- Duplicate keys are not allowed
- The order of keys is not preserved and therefore not reliable
- Retrieving a single item is fast (esp. for many items)
- Improved readability of lookup tables

Comment: So really then a two column table is not especially a good model because you can't have duplicate keys and order is irrelevant. 

Maybe if I think of the key as a label, and the dict as a particular space where labels map onto "definitions" aka values.

Comment: I think that model will work for my headspace, a dict is an unsorted cloud of "floating" labels that contain definitions/values. you can't have duplicate labels because then you would be simply overwriting the existing label(key) - as the label represents the location of that particular container. But no such restriction exists on what's in the container that has the label on it.

Comment: @Sindyr Yes, I think you get it now. Another analogy is a street address. They have to be unique but what is at that address can be anything, a business, a house, etc. But the cool thing with dictionaries is that you get to decide what those labels should be, so your code becomes very readable and looking up those values is very fast. Good luck and happy coding!